# Contraction with general noun

Tags: verbs

is or has contraction occurs with the general nouns other than pronoun?

> a. Pam is one of the great artists.

> b. Pam's one of the great artists.

Is Sentence b also possible? Definitely I've never seen it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly possible in informal conversation. The author of a book wouldn't write *Rembrandt's one of the great artists*, but you might say it to a friend.